# Controller is working in admin side but adding Template or block not call or (display)?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, layout, blocks

add config file it display admin side as sub menu name (New Address)

```
<admin>
     <routers>
         <test>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
               <module>Pfay_Test</module>
               <frontName>admintest</frontName>
            </args>
         </test>
      </routers>
 </admin>
 <adminhtml>
   <layout>
      <updates>
          <test>
              <file>test.xml</file>
           </test>
      </updates>
   </layout>
   <menu>
      <test translate="title" module="adminhtml">
         <title>My Pugins</title>
         <sort_order>100</sort_order>
         <children>
             <set_time>
                   <title>Adress book</title>
                   <action>admintest/adminhtml_index</action>
              </set_time>
              <submenu translate="title" module="adminhtml">
                                        <title>New Address</title>
                                        <action>admintest/adminhtml_test/</action>
                                    </submenu>
          </children>
       </test>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

Create controller file it's name is Test

```
class Pfay_Test_Adminhtml_TestController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  public function indexAction()
  {

          $this->loadLayout();
          $this->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

adding my layout file test.xml

```
<test_adminhtml_index_index_test>
     <reference name="content">
            <block type="test/monblock"  name="afficher_monbloc"
                  template="test/test2.phtml" />
                  <block type="test/adminhtml_grid" name="test" />
      </reference>
   </test_adminhtml_index_index_test>
```

Can You Please solve this?

Comment: <children>
               <index module="adminhtml" translate="title">
                    <title>Adress book</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>admintest/adminhtml_index</action>
                </index>
             <list module="adminhtml" translate="title">
                    <title>Test book</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <action>admintest/adminhtml_test</action>
                </list>
          </children>

Comment: <test_adminhtml_test_index>
     <reference name="content">
            <block type="test/monblock"  name="afficher_monbloc"
                  template="test/test2.phtml" />
                  <block type="test/adminhtml_Testgrid" name="test" />  
                  
      </reference>
   </test_adminhtml_test_index>

Comment: I will add in config file in first comment. and second comment i am add test.xml file in admin layout. issue is very small </test_adminhtml_index_index_test> instaed of </test_adminhtml_test_index> call the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your admin url is `admintest/adminhtml_index` then the layout handle should be `<admintest_adminhtml_index_index>` not `<test_adminhtml_index_index_test>`.
Same goes for  `admintest/adminhtml_test`. The layout handles should be `<admintest_adminhtml_test_index>`

the layout handle is built like this `namespace_controller_action`.
if the controller name looks like this `controller_name` then it should be `namespace_controller_name_action`.
If the action is missing then it defaults to `index`.

Comment: It's true. I was finding a solution In My last comment. Thank you very Much For Answer Me. You say Me it's also right.

Comment: @JaydipsinhParmar. When you ask a question and find a solution later, don't post is as a comment. Post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. This way the question is marked as answered and may help future readers.

Comment: Is It's Ok, Now?

Comment: @JaydipsinhParmar. I was saying that you could have added an answer yourself and mark your answer as accepted. Not that you have to mark my answer. :)

Comment: Hello Marius, It's Another Question Plaese check it [My Controller Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31395/create-simple-controller-not-working-in-my-module)