# Magento 1 - Create Simple Controller Not Working In My Module?

Tags: module, magento-1, controllers

I am Trying To create a Simple Module. It's Found 404 page Error.

My config file in app/etc/module/Ffay_All.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
   <config>
      <modules>
        <Ffay_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
         </Ffay_Test>
       </modules>
    </config>
```

Create Controllrer in app\code\local\Ffay\Test\controllers\IndexController.php

```
class Ffay_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction ()
   {
     echo 'test index';
   }
   public function mamethodeAction ()
   {
     echo 'test mymethod';
    }
}
```

And Create My Plugin xml file in app\code\local\Ffay\Test\etc\config.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Ffay_Test>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Ffay_Test>
     </modules>
     <frontend>       
        <routers>
            <routeurfrontend>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Ffay_Test</module>
                <frontName>testing</frontName>
            </args>
            </routeurfrontend>
        </routers>    
    </frontend>
</config>
```

When I am Write testing in magento in display 404 page error. can You Tell me What's Issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested your code and it seams to work.
I only have 2 comments.
You say you created the file `app/etc/module/Ffay_All.xml`. I assume that's a typo and the correct folder is `app/etc/modules/Ffay_All.xml` (modules instead of module).
I aslo see some spaces in your `config.xml` file at the beginning before `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. remove them.
Also clear the cache.

It worked for me for url `testing` and `testing/index/mamethode`.

Comment: I am removing space in my config file. After trying, but still error 404 page.

Comment: You're also right, I found My the issue. I am check it one space is in my config.xml